# Magento automatically deleting product

Tags: php, magento, centos, product

I use Magento 1.9.3.1, which has automatically deleted product from the catalog without any reason!
I've checked the 3rd-party plugins installed but none of them is involved in this issue.

Has someone experienced something like that?
I don't know where to look for...

Thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: when this event occur....

Comment: any advice? this is totally random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, was an inside job :-)
a 3rd part plugin deleted the out of stock products.